# How change Bootstrap-datepicker language at runtime

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-translate

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap-datepicker along with angular-translate and I just can't change the calendar language neither it's date pattern at runtime. My datepicker code is the following:

```
      $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeEnd', function() {
        $('.projectRecordDate').datepicker({
          format: $filter('translate')('common.datepicker.date'),
          todayHighlight: true,
          autoclose: true,
          language: $filter('translate')('common.datepicker.language'),
          showMeridian: true
        });
      }
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I have the same problem. Changing these settings runtime sort of works if I first call `$('.projectRecordDate').datepicker('remove')` and then initialize again as in your code but using the new settings. However that breaks if user had already selected a value.

Comment: Hey thanks. i don't think this is the prettiest solution but hey, it's working :D I'm using it.